# Escape key is not working in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, binding, keypress

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
```

### expected Result:

when the "escape key" is pressed while typing a value for [name], it should return to its previous value.

### actual Result:

value remains the same even when I press the "escape key"

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6h1bbLm9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are expecting `ctrl-z` key behavior attached to `escape` key as escape key not built to undo your changes on press .

well to achieve this we can use `keydown` event as `keypress` wont detect escape key .

**view:**

```
<input id="test" type="text" data-bind="value: name,event:{keydown :escKey}" />
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data,null,2)"></pre>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var model = function(){
    var self=this;
    self.name= ko.observable("smith");
    self.escKey= function (data, event) {
        if (event && event.keyCode == 27) {
            $('#test').val(data.name());
        }
        return true;
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6h1bbLm9/3/)**

Alternatively you can use `biningHandlers` to achieve similar functionality but keep it as last resort .

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot. but i think i should try to make a custom bindingHandler base on your code because i don't want my viewmodel to access the '#test' element directly. thanks thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks super cool :)

base on super cool's answer I created a custom binding handler to solve this problem. Well it's the same but for me your viewmodel is cleaner if you're going to do it in a bindingHandler.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.cancelOnEscape = {
        init: function (element, accessor) {
            var _accessor = accessor();

            $(element).keydown(function (event) {
                if (event && event.keyCode == 27) {
                    $(element).val(_accessor());
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    };
```

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6h1bbLm9/4/